# React won't call backend (Node) due to CORS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, security, cors

Our client side application, When requesting to Login, sends a CORS issue. The API fails with **CORS error: Preflight Wildcard origin not allowed** . This is a Post request.
We have started sharing cookies with the client, and this issue started coming up suddenly.

What we have added :

1. We have added the WithCredentials: true [client side]
2. On the server side, We have included the res.header with almost all access control allow values. And none of them is a wildcard character. (screenshots added) .

We're not using a wildcard in any Header, still the API throws this error for CORS wildcard not allowed.

Server side Code :
[image]

[image]

Client Side API call.:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: We were able to solve this issue by adding the Allow origin to our CORS library value we were using (when the server boots up). The CORS library (I don't know how and why but) overrides the assigned Origin by "*" if nothing is provided.

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
```

Comment: You are setting a secure cookie in localhost. That could be a problem.

Comment: Hey @LakshyaThakur Thanks for your response, but that does not seem to be the issue. I checked by removing it, still getting the same error. Also, The method execution on the backend is not even starting.

Comment: Hmn. I am assuming your accessControlResponse function is the first middleware function to be triggered when a request comes.

Comment: Hey @LakshyaThakur Yes that's how I have added it. I have also tried hard-coding it right before the res.json value. It still does not work.  I tried removing the "WithCredentials:true" part from the client side, so it gets the response. (However the cookies does not get registered in that case. )

Comment: Please post text as text, not as images of text, for both A11Y and mobile reasons. Most code is text. Please post answers as answers, not as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton 
I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by allowing origin to our CORS library being used (when the server boots up). The CORS library (I don't know how and why but) overrides the assigned Origin by "*" if nothing is provided.

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
```